# What is the best Azure VM for pdf generation?

Tags: performance, azure, pdf, virtual-machine

Follow the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/infrastructure/video-rendering

There are some VMs we can consider to generate pdf file.
My application's main purpose is that generating pdf as fast as possible. However, I do not know how pdf is generated and which resource this process cost most (CPU, GPU, Memory, Disk...).
Could you tell me which kind of VM should I choose?

Thank you.

Comment: I have not tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purpose, the task is compute-intensive, graphics-intensive, and visualization workloads. So you need the [GPU VM sizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-gpu) for your VMs. There are six series VMs for you. And the difference between them is that they are based on different NVIDIA cards.

> Users are able to visualize their graphics intensive workflows on the
>   NV instances to get superior graphics capability and additionally run
>   single precision workloads such as encoding and rendering.

So I think the NV-series virtual machines are most appropriate to you.